# networkx DiGraph 64bit 2.7 cannot be imported

Tags: python, networkx

I have reinstalled networkx several times I cannot get DiGraph to work.

```
import networkx as NX
NX.DiGraph()
```

gives:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DiGraph'

```
from networkx import DiGraph
```

gives:

cannot import name DiGraph

I have checked the source code and DiGraph is present and appears fine.

Comment: One possibility is that you've named one of *your* scripts `networkx.py`, this will lead to Python looking there for the module.

Comment: There is nothing named networkx.py on my machine. I was trying to follow the ffnet examples when I ran into this problem.

Comment: I gave an answer earlier when I didn't yet have enough reputation to comment.  I'm moving that answer to a comment, and deleting the answer:  Try `import networkx` and then `networkx.__file__`.  Is that where you expect it to be getting networkx from?